# Flutter commands not found using Bash or ZSH on Windows

Tags: bash, flutter, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently downloaded and setup the new Windows Terminal on Windows 10. It requires you to download Ubuntu and then install Windows Terminal (UWP); but once you do that, you have access to Bash in Windows.

All of that is working correctly. I then setup ZSH (Oh-My-ZSH) and got that working fine. I can use ZSH to do `git` and `npm` commands but when I try and run any `flutter` commands I get errors. I also get the same errors when i switch my terminal over to `bash`.

My `.bash_profile` has only 1 line in it:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/flutter/bin
```

I would love to get my `flutter commands` working in `bash` and `zsh`. But it currently only works in `cmd`.

My bash files are located at `C:\home\<username>`
and flutter is installed at `C:\flutter`

I have also added `export PATH=$PATH:/flutter/bin` to my `.zshrc` file.
(open ZSH, run `nano ~/.zshrc`)

**.ZSHRC file**
[image: .zshrc file]

**Flutter Doctor**
[image: flutter doctor]

Comment: add `export PATH=$PATH:/flutter/bin` in your .zshrc file also.

Comment: I updated the OP to show that I have in fact added the export path to my .zshrc file -- however, i get the exact same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `$'\r': command not found` means that your script has Windows-style newline endings. I've encountered it often enough I now recognize on sight!

Convert `/mnt/c/flutter/bin/flutter` and any other bash scripts to Unix-style newlines and the problem should go away.

Comment: This was the issue! Found an easy guide [here](https://support.nesi.org.nz/hc/en-gb/articles/218032857-Converting-from-Windows-style-to-UNIX-style-line-endings)